# Breaker box location in same room as water heater, washer and dryer

Tags: water, breaker-box

We are remodeling and need to know if the breaker box, hot water heater, washer and dryer can be in the same small room

Comment: Can you give us a dimensioned floorplan of said room?  The main requirement here is *working clearance* -- and it's hard to say without knowing the dimensions of the room, the size of the appliances, and where the breaker box is in the room.

Comment: This is a post-a-picture question. There must be a clear pathway to the breaker panel and nothing obstructing access to it (stuff mounted to the wall under it or sitting on the floor will be considered obstruction per fire inspection).

Answer (score 2):

As long as there's enough room, and everything has adequate space around it, there shouldn't be a problem.

Without knowing more about the space (e.g. dimensions, and layout of the equipment), it's difficult to provide any more detail.